# How can I utilise an incremental subset within a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I have a dataset that contains ~40,000 data points on chicken weights over a crop cycle in various sheds(called houses). The main variables are: House Number (1:4), Days in the Crop (Continuous from 0.000001 days up to ~39 days, though some houses end before 39) and Weight in grams (though for the first 0.5-0.8 days the weight is NA since no readings are taken, but these still need to be kept to show growth from day 0).

I'm trying to use a for loop to calculate the average weight each day on a per house basis, and then I want to store that data in a new dataframe. I managed to successfully do this initially by subsetting the data into separate houses and then using the below loop:

```
house_1 <- subset(df,house==1)

daily_averages <- data.frame(Day = 1:39, Average=NA)
for (i in 1:1){
            lower = 0
            upper = 1
            weight = house_1$weight
            days = house_1$days_in_crop
                        for (meanroll in 1:39) {
                          meanroll_val = mean(weight[days > lower & days < upper],na.rm=TRUE)
                          daily_averages$Average[meanroll] <- meanroll_val
                          lower=lower+1
                          upper=upper+1
              }
}
```

This gives me a dataframe containing the average for each day, but only for House 1. Where Lower is the lower value of the day e.g. Start at 0 and Upper is the upper value of the day e.g. end of day 0 is 1 so any value between 0 and 1 is the first day. The i in 1:1 was so I didn't need to reset the lower and upper everytime I run it but also to allow me to *hopefully* convert it to using all 4 houses at once.

After this I tried building a second for loop that would store all averages for each day for each house in a single dataframe, what I have so far is below:

```
house_ID <- unique(df$house)
daily_data <- data.frame(HouseNumber=NA, Day = rep(1:39,length(house_ID), Average= NA)
    
     for (house_no in 1:length(house_ID)){
       lower= 0
       upper = 1
       weight = df$weight
       days= df$days_in_crop
       house_N <- subset(df,house==house_no)
         with(house_N,
          for(meanroll in 1:39){
            meanroll_val = mean(weight[days > lower & days < upper],na.rm=TRUE)
            daily_data$Average[meanroll] <- meanroll_val
            lower=lower+1
            upper=upper+1
          })
     }
```

Instead no values are being stored, I've also tried replacing

```
daily_data$Average[meanroll] <- meanroll_val
```

with

```
print(meanroll_val)
```

To see if the issue was not iterating through the subsets, instead I receive some values, followed by many NaN, some more values then some more NaN (though the combined number of values and NaN does total 156, 4*39)

Is there a better way to achieve this? I could just copy the output of the first for loop for each house, but in the future I'm likely to have many more houses so it will be more practical to have the second for loop

ETA: I also realise houses are not being assigned in that second for loop, but since it's also not working when using Print instead of storing the data, I don't think that's the issue

ETA: output of

```
dput(head(df, 20))
```

is:

```
structure(list(house = c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), days_in_crop = c(0.000856481, 
0.001435185, 0.002025463, 0.003252315, 0.003657407, 0.003738426, 
0.004479167, 0.005451389, 0.007766204, 0.008333333, 0.008912037, 
0.010138889, 0.010497685, 0.010555556, 0.011365741, 0.012361111, 
0.01462963, 0.015231481, 0.015798611, 0.017025463), weight = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

A subset containing only days over 9 (note value is 9.1 since chickens tend to be sleeping at the start of the day so are not on sensors):

```
days_9_39 <- subset(df,days_in_crop > 9.1)
dput(head(days_9_39, 20))

structure(list(house = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L), days_in_crop = c(9.101712963, 
9.101944444, 9.102847222, 9.10318287, 9.103229167, 9.106064815, 
9.106145833, 9.1065625, 9.10837963, 9.108900463, 9.109849537, 
9.110162037, 9.112581019, 9.113032407, 9.113159722, 9.114247685, 
9.11462963, 9.116435185, 9.117118056, 9.119236111), weight = c(244L, 
255L, 249L, 260L, 259L, 276L, NA, 260L, 254L, 254L, 244L, 265L, 
268L, NA, 300L, 250L, 239L, 255L, 251L, 258L)), row.names = 10262:10281, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Why do you indent the code with so much space?

Comment: You probably don't need a for loop at all, but a reproducible example would help address that.  Is the "Days in the Crop" variable truly continuous (how is it measured) or is it an integer (day 1, day 2, day 3 etc..)

Comment: The day is truly continuous, there are weighing sensors in the chicken sheds constantly record data, this is sent every 10 minutes and the day value has been converted from the date format to be continuous between day 0 and end day

E.g. you may have a recording at day 0.059571759, and another at day 0.064108796 all the way up to day 38.34743, when chickens are removed

Comment: The first few hundred entries in weight are likely to be NAs as chickens are not introduced until later into the first day (i.e. between day 0 and day 1), however, later analyses might need to use that to see which sensors and/or houses have the fewest readings, which is why I opted to use na.rm in the for loop, as opposed to removing them from the original dataframe, this might not be wise; I'm unsure

Comment: @coghlan Thanks! ButYou posted exactly what I asked for but there's a problem, all days are day 0, so all weights are NA. Can  repost data with a more representative subset of it? For instance, select a couple of chickens and post 3 or 4 days of those.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have done so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.
`by` splits the data by house, then `aggregate`s by the integer part of `days_in_crop`.

```r
res <- by(days_9_39, days_9_39$house, \(X) {
  X$days_in_crop <- floor(X$days_in_crop)
  agg <- aggregate(weight ~ days_in_crop, X, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  agg$house <- X$house[1]
  agg[c(3, 1, 2)]
})

res <- do.call(rbind, res)
res
#>   house days_in_crop   weight
#> 1     1            9 260.1667
#> 2     2            9 280.0000
#> 3     3            9 252.4000
#> 4     4            9 251.6000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

A simpler solution is to aggregate weight by all other variables, with integer days.
The changed `days_in_crop` is [`local`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) only.

```r
res2 <- local({
  days_9_39$days_in_crop <- floor(days_9_39$days_in_crop)
  aggregate(weight ~ ., days_9_39, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
})
res2
#>   house days_in_crop   weight
#> 1     1            9 260.1667
#> 2     2            9 280.0000
#> 3     3            9 252.4000
#> 4     4            9 251.6000

all.equal(res, res2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit 2

To include other aggregate statistics, create a temporary, local function with all wanted statistics but note that the results column is a matrix, the result must be slightly processed before returning.

```r
res3 <- local({
  f <- function(x) {
    c(mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))
  }
  days_9_39$days_in_crop <- floor(days_9_39$days_in_crop)
  agg <- aggregate(weight ~ ., days_9_39, f)
  cbind(agg[-ncol(agg)], agg[[ncol(agg)]])
})
res3
#>   house days_in_crop     mean        sd
#> 1     1            9 260.1667 10.998485
#> 2     2            9 280.0000 28.284271
#> 3     3            9 252.4000  2.701851
#> 4     4            9 251.6000 10.620734
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That works, but if I also then wanted to add an extra column, such as one for Standard Deviation, where would I insert sd?